# Query to filter Accounts with specific products, using Opportunity LineItem

Tags: soql, relationships

I wanted to pull in a query all of our customers that have bought an specific product,I tried to do it like this, but I got an error telling me that I cannot have more than 1 level of relationships:

```
select ID From Account 
  WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT Opportunity.AccountId FROM OpportunityLineItem)
```

I really don't want to pull the data a bunch of times, so I'm desperate to do it in one line of SOQL code.

Comment: N.B. the query doesn't seem to specify a product of interest. Your query is finding all accounts without any Opportunity Products (notwithstanding the error you received)

Answer (score 1):

You can add formula field in Opportunity Product that will display the Opportunity.AccountId and then :

```
SELECT Id FROM Account 
  WHERE Id IN (SELECT Account_Id__c FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE Product2ID ='<ID>')
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to query for opps with this line item and then take the accounts from the result. You can group the lines by account, but this is limited to 2k returned lines.

```
SELECT AccountId FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN (SELECT OpportunityId FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE Product2Id = '123')
GROUP BY AccountId
```

Or you can take this one level deeper a query just for that opportunity lines and then take the accounts from that.

```
SELECT Opportunity.AccountId FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE Product2Id = ''
GROUP BY Opportunity.AccountId
```

Again the `group by` is optional.